# RealmMigration erased every data in my realm

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-migration

Today I changed my application realm schema, and so I implemented a Migration.
Inside the migration, I just needed to add a field, so I did:

```
 if (oldVersion == 0) {
    RealmObjectSchema class = schema.get("Class");
    class.addField("addedField", boolean.class, null)
       .transform(new RealmObjectSchema.Function() {
           @Override
           public void apply(DynamicRealmObject obj) {
              obj.set("addedField", false);
           }
       });
       oldVersion++;
}
```

But this erased everything in my realm, I got no more data.

This is not a problem as I'm still in dev phase. I did the migration instead of uninstalling/reinstalling the app just to learn how to implement a RealmMigration.

Did I do something wrong? Is it normal that I got everything erased? Did I need to add some more code? 
I already read the documentation and had a look at the sample app. The code provided didn't got anything more.

Realm configuration:

```
Realm.init(this);
RealmConfiguration newConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
   .name("myRealm.realm")
   .schemaVersion(1)
   .migration(new SchemaMigration())
   .build();
```

And at least:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(newConfig);
```

## EDIT:

I solved this by **removing** the `name("myRealm.realm")`. At the first installation I didn't use a `RealmConfiguration` so the name of the realm was: "default.realm". Thank you guys for your support and your answers!

Comment: You probably have `deleteIfMigrationNeeded()` set on your RealmConfiguration.Builder, which is checked before migration is attempted.

Comment: No I don't. I'll update the answer with the code of config as well

Answer (score 1):

Try do not pass `null` as a field attributes and use type specific setter (`setBoolean`) for transformation of `DynamicRealmObject`:

```
if (oldVersion == 0) {
    RealmObjectSchema class = schema.get("Class");
    class.addField("addedField", boolean.class)
         .transform(new RealmObjectSchema.Function() {
             @Override
             public void apply(DynamicRealmObject obj) {
             obj.setBoolean("addedField", false);
         }
    });
    oldVersion++;
}
```

Comment: This helped, but I think the problem was related to the name. At the first installation I didn't use a RealmConfiguration. So the name of the realm was `default.realm`. I deleted the row `.name("myRealm.realm")` and it worked, it kept the entire old realm. I'll upvote this answer as I think removing null as attributes is a good point, plus `setBoolean()` is beetter then `set()`. Thank you guy!